# Margem extra aparecendo em elementos com display input-block. Como resolver?

Tags: css

Estou com um problema no meu css. Estava elaborando um estilo para formatar alguns botões. Tudo ocorreu bem. Porém, os meus botões estão com uma margem extra aparecendo. Ou seja, eu não defini margem nos meus botões, porém eles estão aparecendo com margem.

Exemplo:

```css
.container .item{
    background-color: lightgreen;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <button class="item">Item</button>
  <button class="item">Item</button>
  <button class="item">Item</button>
</div>
```

Perceba que eu defini que o botão teria `margin:0`, porém o mesmo está com margem.

Eu percebi que o problema acontece por causa do `inline-block`, pois quando eu troco para `block` com `float:left` o problema é resolvido. Veja:

```css
.container .item {
   float: left;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   margin:0;
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

      <button class="item">Item</button>
      <button class="item">Item</button>
      <button class="item">Item</button>
    </div>
```

Porém `float:left` nesse caso não é desejável, pois, por exemplo, costumo a usar `text-align:right` para mudar os alinhamentos dos botões, e isso não funciona com `float:left`.

Existe alguma maneira de remover essas margens extras que estão aparecendo, sem tirar o `inline-block` dos meus botões?

Answer (score 2):

Ele coloca esses espaços para separar os elementos que "estão na mesma linha", como os espaços que colocamos entre uma palavra e outra. É "padrão" isso.

Para resolver você pode:

**1)** Negativar a `margin-left` ou `margin-right` de cada elemento ([exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/5y8egohb/1/));

**2)** Deixar os elementos lado a lado no código `HTML`, sem quebra de linha ou espaço ([exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/5y8egohb/)).

Até existem outros jeitos de contornar essas situações, mas acredito que com essas duas alternativas já irá solucionar seu problema.

Comment: Eu não entendi porquê deram -1. A resposta não está errada.

Answer (score 0):

Deixar sua `<div class="container">` com `display: flex;` ou `display: table;` resolve, mas não sei se ira te atrapalhar no seu alinhamento dos botões